# Possuo um dataframe que preciso selecionar a coluna CHUVA e identificar o maior valor e o menor valor e recebo erro de KeyError: 'chuva'

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, orientação-a-objetos, pandas

```
import pandas as pd

# Data Analisada

    data = int(input('Qual data será analisada? '))

# Coletando df

    df = pd.read_excel('teste2.xlsx', index_col=[0], dtype={'CHUVA': str}).reset_index()

# Identificando Maior chuva

    dia_max = df.loc[(df['DIA'] == data)]
    
    chuva_max = dia_max.loc[dia_max['CHUVA'].idxmax()]
    
    chuva_max_maior = chuva_max.loc['CHUVA'] 
    
    chuva_max_maior_mp = chuva_max.loc['MUNICIPIO']

    print(dia_max)
    print('-----------------------teste-------------------')
    print(chuva_max)
    print(f'{chuva_max_maior}')
    print(f'{chuva_max_maior_mp}')
```

Dados utilizados:

| DIA | MIN | MAX | CHUVA | MUNICIPIO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31 | 22 | 37 | 3,5 | Alto Parnaíba |
| 31 | 22 | 35 | 1,2 | Bacabal |
| 31 | 23 | 35 | 0,5 | Caxias |
| 31 | 23 | 37 | 3,4 | Imperatriz |
| 31 | 23 | 36 | 3,5 | Grajaú |
| 31 | 23 | 35 | 3,5 | S. Benedito do Rio Preto |
| 31 | 23 | 35 | 1,2 | Vargem Grande |
| 31 | 23 | 32 | 0 | Turiaçú |
| 31 | 24 | 37 | 3,9 | Balsas |
| 31 | 24 | 35 | 0 | Pedreiras |
| 31 | 24 | 35 | 1,8 | Codó |
| 31 | 24 | 35 | 0 | Santa Inês |
| 31 | 24 | 34 | 0 | Pinheiro |
| 31 | 24 | 34 | 1,9 | Carolina |
| 31 | 24 | 30 | 0,5 | São Luís |
| 1 | 22 | 36 | 2,9 | Balsas |
| 1 | 23 | 34 | 5,2 | Grajaú |
| 1 | 23 | 33 | 2,5 | Carolina |
| 1 | 23 | 37 | 5 | Alto Parnaíba |
| 1 | 24 | 34 | 1,8 | Bacabal |
| 1 | 24 | 35 | 0,5 | Pedreiras |
| 1 | 24 | 35 | 2,8 | Caxias |
| 1 | 24 | 35 | 2,5 | Codó |
| 1 | 24 | 33 | 0,5 | Pinheiro |
| 1 | 24 | 38 | 4,2 | Imperatriz |
| 1 | 24 | 35 | 2,3 | Santa Inês |
| 1 | 24 | 31 | 3,1 | Turiaçú |
| 1 | 25 | 35 | 1,8 | S. Benedito do Rio Preto |
| 1 | 25 | 32 | 1,2 | São Luís |
| 1 | 25 | 34 | 2,9 | Vargem Grande |
| 2 | 24 | 38 | 3,9 | Alto Parnaíba |
| 2 | 24 | 37 | 2,7 | Imperatriz |
| 2 | 24 | 36 | 0,9 | Caxias |
| 2 | 24 | 36 | 0,5 | Vargem Grande |
| 2 | 23 | 36 | 1,9 | Balsas |
| 2 | 24 | 35 | 0,6 | S. Benedito do Rio Preto |
| 2 | 24 | 35 | 1,2 | Santa Inês |
| 2 | 24 | 34 | 1,2 | Pedreiras |
| 2 | 24 | 34 | 0,3 | Codó |
| 2 | 24 | 34 | 1,5 | Carolina |
| 2 | 23 | 33 | 0 | Bacabal |
| 2 | 24 | 33 | 2,9 | Grajaú |
| 2 | 24 | 33 | 2,5 | Pinheiro |
| 2 | 25 | 33 | 0,8 | Turiaçú |
| 2 | 25 | 32 | 1 | São Luís |
| 3 | 22 | 33 | 3,6 | Bacabal |
| 3 | 22 | 31 | 0,9 | Grajaú |
| 3 | 22 | 34 | 2 | Pedreiras |
| 3 | 23 | 33 | 7,9 | Caxias |
| 3 | 23 | 34 | 0,2 | Codó |
| 3 | 24 | 35 | 0,4 | S. Benedito do Rio Preto |
| 3 | 26 | 30 | 0,4 | São Luís |
| 3 | 24 | 34 | 0,2 | Vargem Grande |
| 3 | 23 | 34 | 0 | Pinheiro |
| 3 | 23 | 32 | 0,8 | Imperatriz |
| 3 | 24 | 34 | 1,1 | Santa Inês |
| 3 | 25 | 31 | 0 | Turiaçú |
| 3 | 22 | 32 | 2 | Balsas |
| 3 | 23 | 33 | 4,2 | Carolina |
| 3 | 22 | 32 | 15 | Alto Parnaíba |
| 4 | 26 | 30 | 0,8 | São Luís |
| 4 | 25 | 31 | 2 | Turiaçú |
| 4 | 24 | 35 | 0 | Codó |
| 4 | 24 | 36 | 0 | S. Benedito do Rio Preto |
| 4 | 24 | 35 | 0 | Vargem Grande |
| 4 | 24 | 34 | 0 | Pinheiro |
| 4 | 24 | 34 | 0,6 | Santa Inês |
| 4 | 23 | 34 | 0 | Bacabal |
| 4 | 23 | 34 | 0 | Pedreiras |
| 4 | 23 | 34 | 0 | Caxias |
| 4 | 23 | 32 | 2,2 | Imperatriz |
| 4 | 22 | 32 | 3,8 | Grajaú |
| 4 | 22 | 31 | 3 | Balsas |
| 4 | 22 | 30 | 9 | Carolina |
| 4 | 21 | 32 | 4,7 | Alto Parnaíba |
| 5 | 23 | 34 | 0 | Bacabal |
| 5 | 22 | 33 | 0,4 | Grajaú |
| 5 | 23 | 34 | 0 | Pedreiras |
| 5 | 23 | 33 | 0,6 | Caxias |
| 5 | 23 | 35 | 0 | Codó |
| 5 | 24 | 35 | 1 | S. Benedito do Rio Preto |
| 5 | 26 | 31 | 2,4 | São Luís |
| 5 | 24 | 35 | 0,5 | Vargem Grande |
| 5 | 23 | 35 | 1 | Pinheiro |
| 5 | 23 | 33 | 0 | Imperatriz |
| 5 | 24 | 35 | 0,3 | Santa Inês |
| 5 | 25 | 31 | 1,1 | Turiaçú |
| 5 | 22 | 32 | 3,4 | Balsas |
| 5 | 23 | 33 | 2 | Carolina |
| 5 | 23 | 33 | 9,2 | Alto Parnaíba |
| 6 | 24 | 34 | 2,7 | Bacabal |
| 6 | 22 | 31 | 16 | Grajaú |
| 6 | 24 | 34 | 2 | Pedreiras |
| 6 | 24 | 34 | 0,8 | Caxias |
| 6 | 24 | 35 | 5 | Codó |
| 6 | 24 | 37 | 0 | S. Benedito do Rio Preto |
| 6 | 26 | 30 | 0,8 | São Luís |
| 6 | 24 | 36 | 0 | Vargem Grande |
| 6 | 24 | 35 | 0,2 | Pinheiro |
| 6 | 23 | 31 | 24 | Imperatriz |
| 6 | 24 | 34 | 3 | Santa Inês |
| 6 | 25 | 32 | 1,1 | Turiaçú |
| 6 | 23 | 29 | 15 | Balsas |
| 6 | 23 | 29 | 6,7 | Carolina |
| 6 | 23 | 31 | 17 | Alto Parnaíba |

Estes dados eu não consegui colocar da melhor forma porém se alguém quiser posso enviar por email ou de outra maneira.

Comment: Já tentou usar [`.min`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.min.html) , [`.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html)  ? Pelo que você diz deve ser o suficiente para pegar os dados que você deseja - Ex. [Ideone](https://ideone.com/1Hr4T0), caso não seja isso, vale apena você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar melhor o que esta tentando fazer

Comment: meu objetivo é identificar qual o maior e menor valor de chuva dos municípios, já consegui fazer o mesmo pra temperatura mas quando chega na chuva não consigo ler o dado.

Tentei usar .min e .max e apresenta erro novamente. Obrigado por responder !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Aqui eu tive o seguinte resultado abaixo. Mas tive que alterar o dtype de STR para FLOAT dtype={'CHUVA': float}

A sua coluna chuva não é um número inteiro, portanto mesmo em texto ele não consegue fazer a leitura correta para determinar qual será o maior/menor e etc...

Qual data será analisada? 5
DIA  MIN  MAX  CHUVA                 MUNICIPIO
75    5   23   34    0.0                   Bacabal
76    5   22   33    0.4                    Grajaú
77    5   23   34    0.0                 Pedreiras
78    5   23   33    0.6                    Caxias
79    5   23   35    0.0                      Codó
80    5   24   35    1.0  S. Benedito do Rio Preto
81    5   26   31    2.4                  São Luís
82    5   24   35    0.5             Vargem Grande
83    5   23   35    1.0                  Pinheiro
84    5   23   33    0.0                Imperatriz
85    5   24   35    0.3                Santa Inês
86    5   25   31    1.1                   Turiaçú
87    5   22   32    3.4                    Balsas
88    5   23   33    2.0                  Carolina
89    5   23   33    9.2             Alto Parnaíba
-----------------------teste-------------------
DIA                      5
MIN                     23
MAX                     33
CHUVA                  9.2
MUNICIPIO    Alto Parnaíba
Name: 89, dtype: object
9.2
Alto Parnaíba

Comment: Foi isso mesmo, funcionou para mim. Muito obrigado pela sua contribuição amigo !